# ydn-db: how do I clear a collection?

Tags: javascript, ydn-db

I want to do something analogous to SQL's `DELETE FROM table1`. There is a `remove` function that takes something called a `KeyRange` but I'm not sure how to create a `KeyRange` that represents "all keys" or if that's even possible.

I can do this:

```js
storage.values("mytable").done(function(result) {
  _.each(result, function(r) {
    storage.remove("mytable", r._id);
  });
});
```

But not only is that ugly, I'd need to do extra work with promises in order to have a callback that's only executed once all the results are finished deleting.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `clear` method. The different is use `remove` if you know record (s), otherwise use clear. `clear` is faster than `remove`. Btw you can use remove method to clear whole table by giving `null` as argument. Then you got number of records removed.